# How can I connect applications running with WINE to the internet?

Tags: wine, internet-connection

I can't get internet accesson something like internet download manager, no errors or anything but it just won't connect.
And how  to integrate WINE applications with native running applications like opera?

Answer (score 1):

I use TeamViewer with WINE. Internet connection is readily available. I think WINE handles it transparently.

To investigate the problem, open a terminal, and type

```
$ wine path_to_the_program
```

you will see some informative output with warnings and errors, that might help.